# How to wrap http.Handler in method

Tags: go, go-http

The simplest way to get file system in go is the code below.

```
http.Handle("/files", http.StripPrefix(pathPrefix, http.FileServer(root)))
```

But for the purpose of objective design, I prefer to wrap the body of function in the method like this.

```
f := file{}
http.Handle("/download", f.download)
http.Handle("/upload", f.upload)
```

How should I wrap the content of code in the file struct method?

Comment: Use `http.HandleFunc` as @BrunoReis suggested and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957455/difference-between-http-handle-and-http-handlefunc) you find the difference between them and why you should use.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `http.HandleFunc` rather than `http.Handle`:

```
f := file{}
http.HandleFunc("/download", f.download)
http.HandleFunc("/upload", f.upload)
```

Assuming it has the right signature (ie, assuming that `f.download` is defined as something like `func (f file) download(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`), then it should do what you want.