# Rate limit specific endpoints

Tags: go, rate-limiting, go-http

I am new to GoLang and working on my first API.  I have two endpoints, and I want to rate limit only one of them. I found a [helpful tutorial](https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/how-to-rate-limit-http-requests) to get me started, and I've based my approach off of the tutorial, recognizing that this approach will rate limit both of my endpoints:

```
var limiter = rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every((1*time.Hour)/3), 1)

func limit(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        if limiter.Allow() == false {
            http.Error(res, http.StatusText(429), http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(res, req)
    })
}

func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", createNewToken)
    mux.HandleFunc("/notify", sendPushNotificationToAllTokens)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":5050", "localhost.crt", "localhost.key", limit(mux)))
}
```

I researched the difference between [http.Handle and http.HandleFunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957455/difference-between-http-handle-and-http-handlefunc) and naively believed that I could substitute `http.HandleFunc`  for `http.Handle`. This approach is completely flawed as the logic contained in the `HandlerFunc` never executes:

```
var limiter = rate.NewLimiter(rate.Every(1*time.Hour/3), 1)

func limit(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        if limiter.Allow() == false {
            http.Error(res, http.StatusText(429), http.StatusTooManyRequests)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(res, req)
    }
}

func main() {
    //mux := http.NewServeMux()
    http.HandleFunc("/", createNewToken)
    http.HandleFunc("/notify", sendPushNotificationToAllTokens)

    // attempt to only rate limit the /notify endpoint 
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":5050", "localhost.crt", "localhost.key", limit(sendPushNotificationToAllTokens)))
```

Can anyone explain why this does not work, and how I could approach this problem to only rate limit a specific endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distinction between using a plain `http.Handler` and a `http.HanlderFunc` doesn't really matter here. `http.HandleFunc` is just a way to convert a regular function into a `http.Handler` - it essentially does the same thing as your original version of `limit`.

Your implementations of `limit` both look fine; probably the second is better because it's simpler. Instead, the issue is in `main`. When you call `http.ListenAndServeTLS` and provide a value for the final argument, it requests that only the handler you pass in as that final argument be used as the root request handler. Any calls to `http.Handle()` or `http.HandleFunc()` are ignored unless you pass in `nil` as this final argument.

What you want to do instead is apply `limit` to the specific handler you want to limit. You have two options for this. First, you can use a `ServeMux` like in your first code snippet:

```golang
func main() {
    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.HandleFunc("/", createNewToken)
    // Limit only the handler for "/notify".
    mux.HandleFunc("/notify", limit(sendPushNotificationToAllTokens))

    // Don't limit the whole mux.
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":5050", "localhost.crt", "localhost.key", mux))
}
```

Alternatively, you can do something more like your second code snippet, but pass in `nil` for the final argument to `http.ListenAndServeTLS` so that the default `http.ServeMux` is used, meaning that the calls to `http.HandleFunc()` will be respected:

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", createNewToken)
    // Limit only the handler for "/notify".
    http.HandleFunc("/notify", limit(sendPushNotificationToAllTokens))

    // Pass in nil here so that http.DefaultServeMux is used.
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":5050", "localhost.crt", "localhost.key", nil))
}
```

For a simple application, the first approach is probably fine. For anything more complex, I'd recommend the later approach because it will work if you open multiple servers or do other more complex things.